# Laravel 4 App Show White Screen/Page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**Description**

I've not been working on Laravel 4 environment for about 2 years now. Now, I'm trying to help a friend out, and make some modification to the site. While trying to get the site up and running, I faced some errors.

---

**Steps**

- Clone the project from repository
- Run `composer update`
- Run `chmod  -R 777 public/vendor/ bootstrap/ app/storage`
- Restart MAMP server on my Mac OS.
- Run `sudo composer update`

> php artisan clear-compiled
>   PHP Warning:  require(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/bootstrap/environment.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/bootstrap/start.php on line 31
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/bootstrap/environment.php' (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.41/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/bootstrap/start.php on line 31

Why do I get this permission issues ? 
I thought **chmod -R 777** will take care of this ....

**Result**

- Still, my site displaying just white page

[image]

---

## Logs

apache_error.log

```
Wed Oct 26 19:13:33 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.6.10 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 26 19:18:42 2016] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/public/docs-assets, referer: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English
[Thu Oct 27 07:54:53 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 27 07:56:16 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Oct 27 07:56:16 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Oct 27 07:56:16 2016] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 69323)
[Thu Oct 27 07:56:16 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.6.10 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

php_error.log

```
[27-Oct-2016 14:16:28 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/bootstrap/environment.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/bootstrap/start.php on line 31
[27-Oct-2016 14:16:28 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/bootstrap/environment.php' (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/bootstrap/start.php on line 31
```

Comment: can you include the routes

Comment: the entire `routes.php` ? OR just some ...

Comment: better the entire maybe there's an error inside the routes

Comment: You should check the laravel log and the apache error log.

Comment: yey check the error log to know the latest error you got

Comment: the laravel error log project\storage\logs\laravel.logs

Comment: I've update my post with my PHP, and Apache logs, and I don't see anything in my laravel logs.

Comment: you did not see in project\storage\logs\laravel.logs?

Comment: No, all I see what's in there is a `.gitignore file`.

Comment: composer update

Comment: _“Why do I get this permission issues ?”_ – what makes you think “No such file or directory” would be a permissions issue?

Comment: Ahh. You are right  ! I'm so stupid. So does that mean it is looking for an environment.php file ? And it's not there ? I just did a fresh clone. How is that happening?

Comment: @CBroe : Your comment is the key to my problem. I want to thank-you for that. :D

Answer (score 0):

It occurred because your are lacking of some vendor files. to add the vendor files.

try running

```
composer install
```

or

```
composer update
```

Comment: I did. I tried sudo composer update. I got errors. Please see me steps on my post.

Comment: can I see your composer

Comment: composer version ? `Composer version 1.2.1 2016-09-12 11:27:19`    what you mean by see ?

Comment: I mean your laravel composer.json

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks for your willingness and trying to help !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@CBroe** comment

*“Why do I get this permission issues ?”* – what makes you think “No such file or directory” would be a permissions issue?

I realize I need to create

**/bootstrap/environment.php**

```
<?php
return 'local';
```

Then, that white screen is no-longer there, and I finally see my site load for the first time.